# Get or copy external dependency folder in dockerfile while building image

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, git-clone

I m building my project in dockerfile. While it is building it needs some external dlls in a external git repository folder. When I tried git clone in dockerfile I faced 504 unable access error.Git repositories in internal addres in company not github. I tried many ways about git cloning but I could not succes git cloning in dockerfile. Also I tried remove proxy settings, too. Could you suggest me a way how I can get external dlls to my dockerfile while creating image build?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to download that external dll as static dll file in your code. Then build the container with the local dll file and copy into the container. The static file is under your control even if one day you want to update it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a basic docker image that contains all DLLs lets call it `dll-source`. In your application docker image using `multistage builder` add DLLs from `dll-source` docker image.